# ASUS N552VW battery level stuck, not charging

Tags: battery, asus

Laptop Asus model N552VW. Ubuntu 19.10. The laptop works from AC for all 3 years of its usage (the battery is not unpluggable easily, so it stayed all the time).

#### Problems

- Sometimes the battery level icon stuck at "Estimating..".
- Sometimes would not charge above 80%, 83%.
- If switched from AC to battery - UI does not update batter level - stuck at 80%
- After some time the orange light would blink.

[image]

```
upower -e | sed -n 2p | xargs upower -i
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               ASUSTeK
  model:                ASUS Battery
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Tue 03 Dec 2019 10:10:15 AM EET (32 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               charging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              30.78 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         39.81 Wh
    energy-full-design:  48 Wh
    energy-rate:         22.83 W
    voltage:             15 V
    time to full:        23.7 minutes
    percentage:          78%
    capacity:            82.9375%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-full-charging-symbolic'
  History (charge):
    1575360614  78.000  charging
  History (rate):
    1575360614  22.830  charging
```

#### Thoughts

Had similar problems twice in previous 3 years. Each time - the problem get resolved after some time by itself.

Tried to turn off and wait for 5 secs (for a reset).

This time the problem keeps persisting.

Battery degrades with time. However there are still 80% according to the output. I don't mind of the battery (would remove it completely, since it is never used), however the blinking light is annoying. Also the laptop usually stays in *suspend* mode - I don't like the fact that it keeps trying to charge (static orange light).

Comment: there may be a key combination that turns off battery charging ... perhaps you press the combination by accident

Comment: the battery is charging to 80%, if uncharged below 80%. The tools like `tlp` do not work with ASUS. Using the latest 504 BIOS.